# Does Fusion have a tail function?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-fusion

I need a tail-like funciton that can be used like this:

```
boost::fusion::vector<char, int, float> a('a', 12, 5.5f);
boost::fusion::vector<int, float> b(12, 5.5f);

boost::fusion::copy( Tail(a), b );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation for [Boost Fusion](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html), there's a section under *Algorithms* called *Transformation*. The [*Functions*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/transformation/functions.html) listed here notably include one called [`pop_front`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/transformation/functions/pop_front.html). This seems to do exactly what we want:

> Returns a new sequence, with the first element of the original removed.
>   ...
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> assert(pop_front(make_vector(1,2,3)) == make_vector(2,3));
> ```

For your example:

```
boost::fusion::vector<char, int, float> a('a', 12, 5.5f);
boost::fusion::vector<int, float> b(12, 5.5f);

boost::fusion::copy( boost::fusion::pop_front(a), b );
```

---

The name `pop_front` is a little strange, considering that it doesn't actually modify the input sequence, but returns a modified result. However, `pop_front` comes from the C++ standard library, where it is used for removing the first element of a collection such as with [`std::list::pop_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_front). Boost Fusion chose this name to be "more consistent" with the standard library.

Comment: Odd name, given that the library is very functional. :)

Comment: @alfC Yeah. Many C++ libraries use the names from the C++ standard library, even if they are functional

Comment: It also seems to copy the elements instead of generating a sequence of references. That seems to be a big limitation of pop_back

Comment: Maybe if I do a `fusion::transform` I can manage to get rid of the temporary copy. `copy(pop_front(transform(a, [](auto& x)->decltype(auto){return x;})), b);` or even `copy( pop_front(transform(a, [](auto& x){return std::ref(x);})), b)`.

Comment: @alfC I don't believe it does copy. "Complexity: Constant. Returns a view which is lazily evaluated."

Comment: @alfC You can see that it doesn't do an extra copy: https://godbolt.org/z/ZglilB . However, because it returns a constant view, you can't move from it: https://godbolt.org/z/GbxHt5

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the "view" remark in the documentation. It is a pity it doesn't do moves on views. I would use that because I am using this for a spiri x3 parser semantic action and in general the attributes should be moved into the targets (`val`s) because they are not used after the parsing. I think Fusion still needs some upgrading for C++11, in this case some kind of compile-time move-iterator/move-range.